# How do I return multiple values from a function and how to invoke the function and assign the values returned to local variables? (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to SQL Server and I would like to ask a query
Suppose I have a function which returns four values like e.g.

`set @RetValue=@PendingFlag + @Status + @BTFound + @ValueDate` and  `RETURN @RetValue`. 
Now suppose im invoking this function from another function like suppose:

```
DECLARE @d VARCHAR(max)
SET@d=dbo.ValidateBTtype(@BType,@ReadBT,@Type,@Id,@ClientId,@Customerno,@InterestDate,@ApplicationType)
```

In `@d` il have all the four values 
But what I want to do is I want the returned values and I want to store it separately in local variables like local variable `@PendingFlag=`returned value (`@Pending Flag`) local variable `@Status`=returned value (`@Status`) and etc..

Please help me how to store the returned values separately in the second function by invoking the first function

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? (or MySQL or something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return a table from the function, where the table has one row, and four columns, one for each of the return values.

See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for details on table valued functions.

Answer (score 0):

possible approaches here: 
in your `dbo.ValidateBTtype` function to split the four strings (or values) with comma and then split the `@d` string in to 4 parts using comma as delimiter 
like so:
 
`@RetValue= @PendingFlag + ',' + @Status + ',' + @BTFound + ','+ @ValueDate`

...or create table valued function instead..

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279024/return-multiple-values-from-a-sql-server-function) 'How to return multiple values from a sql server function'. Or google 'sql server returning multiple values from function' and take your pick.

Cheers -

Answer (score -1):

You need to look into SQL Concepts .
Use SQlClient Class for making an SQL query .
 Look into DataSet class for it is usually used to store "multiple return values"  
http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlclient

Comment: You can't use a data set in a stored procedure, so this doesn't help. That;'s probably why you've been down voted.